# datagrid and static dataprovider

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, flex4

I'm trying to get this code working, any help would be greatly appreciated.

`<mx:DataGrid x="359" y="221" width="623" height="176">
            <mx:dataProvider>
                  <fx:Object name="Garbage Collection" code="7777" hours="2"/>
                  <fx:Object name="Road Repair" code="8888" hours="6"/>
                  <fx:Object name="Lawn Maintenance" code="9999" hours="12"/>
            </mx:dataProvider>
            <mx:columns>
                <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Column 1" dataField="name"/>
                <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Column 2" dataField="code"/>
                <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Column 3" dataField="hours"/>
            </mx:columns>
        </mx:DataGrid>`

I even don't have he header text in my columns ... I really don't understand.

Thank

Pierre

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the `<fx:Array>` regarding to Adobe: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/DataGrid.html?filter_flex=4.1&filter_flashplayer=10.1&filter_air=2
But it should also work with an array. Is the dataProvider attribut of your DataGrid set, when you debug your application?

Comment: Hi,Actually I used en embedded font ... and the itemrenderer wasn't able to use it !

Answer (score 0):

`<mx:DataGrid x="359" y="221" width="623" height="176">
            <mx:dataProvider>
                  <fx:Object name="Garbage Collection" code="7777" hours="2"/>
                  <fx:Object name="Road Repair" code="8888" hours="6"/>
                  <fx:Object name="Lawn Maintenance" code="9999" hours="12"/>
            </mx:dataProvider>
            <mx:columns>
                <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Column 1" dataField="name"/>
                <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Column 2" dataField="code"/>
                <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Column 3" dataField="hours"/>
            </mx:columns>
        </mx:DataGrid>`

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your `<fx:Object />`'s in an Array:

```
<mx:dataProvider>
    <mx:Array>
        <fx:Object />
    </mx:Array>
</mx:dataProvider>
```